# Can't unescape JSON content in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm generating a JSON file using PHP's json_encode function, and I've escaped double-quote characters with `&#34;`, so the output line looks like this:

```
"apply_instructions":"<p>Visit <a href=&#34;http:\/\/www.google.com&#34;>www.google.com<\/a><\/p>"
```

I'm then using JQuery's `getJSON` function to retrieve and loop through the file. I'm attempting to unencode the `&#34;` using this:

```
entry.apply_instructions = entry.apply_instructions.replace('&#34;', '"');
```

For whatever reason, it's not working. The first quote mark seems to be getting replaced, but the second one won't budge. I've tried using other random find-and-replace characters, with similar results.

Comment: Why did you encode the quotes yourself?

Comment: .replace() only replaces the first instance, you need to use regex to do a global replace.

Comment: php's `json_encode` does all the escaping for you. http://codepad.org/VzT99sqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace()` only replaces the first instance, you need to use regex to do a global replace.

IE:

`.replace(/&#34;/g, "\"");`

Comment: This worked perfectly; thanks. I had to escape it myself for a very specific, one-time reason (CMS integration), so this is the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try not escaping the quotes (in php):

```
$arr = array( 
    "apply_instructions"=>'<p>Visit <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>'
);

echo json_encode($arr); // it will do all the escaping for you
```

See demo: http://codepad.org/VzT99sqM

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regex to replace all instances of `&#34;`.

Or use a different function to escape the quotes using backslashes.